# How to view .ipynb as regular text instead of an IPython notebook in vscode

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, visual-studio-code

VS Code recently added the ability to work with Jupyter Notebooks (`.ipynb` files), this is to say it renders them as notebooks and not the underlying text.

The problem I'm running into is I want to make some edits on the raw text rather than the "notebook" but I can't figure out how to show it as a text file the way any other editor would.

Is there a way to toggle between the views?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Other answers didn't work for me recently. I found no "use notebook editor" option under preferences, perhaps vs code has reorganized recently. Instead I found the following solution. Right click on an *.ipynb file tab to get the context menu, and click "Reopen Editor With..." as pictured below.

[image]

Then on the following popup click "configure default editor for .ipynb", and then click on the text editor as seen below:

[image]

And viola. The default settings have been changed.

Comment: Changing the accepted answer as this is what works now.

Answer (score 32):

### Disable automatically opening `*.ipynb` files in Notebook Editor

To make sure the Jupyter notebooks don't open in the Notebook Editor automatically, make sure to disable this settings. ([Command Palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette) -> Settings)

[image]

**OR**

In the User or Workspace `settings.json`, add the following the root json - `"jupyter.useNotebookEditor": false`

### To toggle between the Notebook Editor and Raw Text Mode Editing

There is an option/command called `Reopen Editor with...`, which will provide you options to open the `*.ipynb` file in text mode.

[image]

You trigger this by performing a Right Click on the Editor Tab (Editor Title Bar) or [Command Palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette) -> `Reopen Editor with...`

[image]
[image]

PS: I have the [Jupyter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-toolsai.jupyter) extension (v2020.12.414227025)

Answer (score 17):

Open: File > Preferences > Settings

Search ipynb and deselect the following:

[image]

Comment: If visual studio code does a mess, as it usually does, and this does not work, just rename the file to another extension, such as `.txt` and then read it.

Answer (score 5):

I think the fastest way is to rename the file.

Just press <kbd>F2</kbd> (or <kbd>return</kbd> for mac) while selecting the file in the vscode explorer, then rename from `my-notebook.ipynb` to `my-notebook.json`, because jupyter ipynb files are [regular json](https://nbformat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/format_description.html) files

Answer (score 3):

(Similar to aquirdturtle's answer) 
What about

#### On the left side explorer

Right Click on file -> Open With -> Text Editor

Answer (score 1):

Create .json file and paste the notebook json in there, save the file and then rename the extension to .ipynb and it will open in the jupyter editor

Answer (score -1):

Set the setting

```
"files.associations": {
  "*.ipynb": "text"
}
```

Or try click on the Status Bar field that shows the `Language Mode` of the file in the lower right.

Use the command: `Change Language Mode`

Comment: there is no language mode in the status bar and using the command pallet it says there's "no text editor active at this time" which I suspect is because it's rendering a notebook using presumably a built in browser.  Changing file associations doesn't work either.

Comment: @user1816847 rename the file to .txt and open with VSC

Comment: hmm yes this is what i'm trying to avoid though :(

Comment: @user1816847 I used notepad++ to edit .ipynb files, search settings for `ipynb` and unmark the open in Notebook editor

Comment: yeah :(  I added sublime text into my work flow to do the one thing i need to do but i'm not happy about adding tools.  Hopefully there will be a way to turn it off in VSCode.

Comment: @user1816847 don't you have vi on your machine or gedit or nano?

Comment: yes.  I've been a vim user for the last 25 years.  There are plenty of workarounds for what I want but that's a bit divergent from my original question.  and keeping everything i need to do in vscode is just the "nicest" solution for me and my definition of "nice"

Comment: @user1816847 Use the setting i mentioned